# Struts2 checkboxlist

Tags: struts2, checkboxlist

I have a Struts checkboxlist `value="val" listkey="lk" listvalue="lv"` and this checkboxlist is iterating and getting 5 checkboxes as per the list in the action class. My quesiton is when I click on first checkbox it should show div element right below the checkbox. Remember theme like "vertical" where we append break br in template. In the same way how can I achieve div element right below the check box when its clicked

Comment: you should post some code, so that people can help you more quickly, you cannot let people guess, what you are willing to do

Comment: please make sure to provide example code since its hard to imagine theoretically.